# spring-data-cassandra-2.0.0.RELEASE + spring-boot-starter-web-1.5.7.RELEASE causes java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: spring-data-cassandra, spring-boot-starter

I use latest available version of spring-data-cassandra which is 2.0.0.RELEASE and latest version of spring-boot-starter-web - 1.5.7.RELEASE

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I can build project without any issues, however application does not start with the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.cassandraMapping
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:109) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:179) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:328) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:271) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:693) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
at Application.main(Application.java:8) [classes/:na]
```

Root cause:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.CassandraMappingContext
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:255) ~[spring-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.addDeducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:356) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
... 21 common frames omitted
```

It looks like the problem is in spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.7.RELEASE , if I update spring-boot-starter-web to 2.0.0.M5:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-libs-snapshot</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M5</version>
 </dependency>
```

then application starts without any errors.

Is there any way to use latest available versions of spring-data-cassandra along with spring-boot-starter-web or should I wait for GA of spring-boot-starter-web:2.0.0 ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Spring Data Cassandra is 2.0.0 which isn't compatible with Spring Boot 1.x. You need to upgrade your dependencies to Spring Boot 2.0 M5.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I faced same problem so here what I did,
FIRST I am connecting multiple keyspace in cassandra and using spring boot which has 
spring boot starter 2.0.0.RELEASE
I deleted version declaration for spring data cassandra, however its managed version is 2.0.5.RELEASE so you can check this.
SECOND I got error when org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.java.AbstractCassandraConfiguration
was imported before and in 2.0.0.RELEASE it is moved to
org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.AbstractCassandraConfiguration
so do check this out